# Cannot connect to Ubuntu Server via SSH over wireless LAN

Tags: 18.04, ssh, raspberrypi

I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 in my Raspberry Pi 3B Plus. I configured everything and successfully log in to my account via SSH Private Key on ethernet. However, when it comes to wireless connection, PuTTY stucks while connection time out appears. Configuration was done here:

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Everything seems pretty well. When I checked built-in **wlan0**, it gets IP address. I don't find out where it is wrong. Any help would be great.

```
$ netstat tlnp
State    Recv-Q    Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port
LISTEN   0         128           127.0.0.53%lo:53               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:35600            0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128                    [::]:35600               [::]:*
```

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.103/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2402sec preferred_lft 2402sec
    inet6 XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.105/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 2405sec preferred_lft 2405sec
    inet6 XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please add output of these commands to your question `ss -tlnp` and `ip a`

Comment: Added command results @marosg

Comment: Your ssh server is not running, there is nothing listening on port 22. How do you login "over ethernet"? Isn't it just your console?

Comment: Yes, it is. I use PuTTY to connect to my RPi over ethernet (Windows 10). In fact, I created RSA Private Key. RPi is connected to the router; Windows PC is also connected to the modem via ethernet. @marosg

Comment: hm, is you ssh listening on port 35600?

Comment: Correct. After installing my Ubuntu Server, I did not install SSH server specifically. Should I do? If so, what is this I am currently using? @marosg P.S. I changed SSH port intentionally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110235/discussion-between-murray-and-marosg).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, It is not a configuration issue.
It is the issue of ip.
type ifconfig and get the ip of wifi connection and use it to connect to the server via ssh. That's it.
If not working, reply with your ssh config in comment.

Comment: ifconfig displays a local address and does not work. here is the configuration file upon your request; I could not manage to post all lines here due to its lenght. All of them has hash sign except those: Port 35600, PasswordAuthentıcatıon no, ChallengeResponseAuthentication no, UsePAM yes, X11Forwarding yes